# Wifi is not working on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi, drivers

I have a Dell Latitude E4310 laptop which ran Ubuntu for the last 4 years (with various versions). Recently I have installed Linux Mint (version 17), and afterwards the WiFi is not working. It was working perfectly under Ubuntu.

What should I do? Is there a driver or package I should install? Here is the output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
03:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 01)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

Also, running `service networking restart` does not work properly:

```
davidlat ~ # service networking restart
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking
davidlat ~ #
```

Update:
Here are the results of `ifconfig -a`

```
davidlat ~ # ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:26:0a:0c:9c:1c  
          inet addr:10.0.0.13  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5e26:aff:fe0c:9c1c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:804913 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:393747 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1066394980 (1.0 GB)  TX bytes:37366404 (37.3 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f5400000-f5420000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:32255 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32255 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3728961 (3.7 MB)  TX bytes:3728961 (3.7 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:27:10:92:61:28  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: let see your output of ifconfig -a It's look like you should rebuild your kernel

Comment: It seems that wlan0 is not up. Try `ip link set  wlan0 up`.  This link was useful for me when I installed Debian. https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse.

Answer (score 0):

Try connect to wifi manually by wpa_supplicant and dhclient. You should run the follow commands:

```
wpa_passphrase ssid password > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhclient wlan0
```

ssid=your wifi name

After exec wpa_supplicant wait it to connect, and move it to bg ( ctrl+z; bg ) or use another terminal to run dhclient.

Answer (score 0):

Usually such problems reflect the unavailability of a proper driver. Try opening `driver-manager` and see if some additional drivers need to be installed.

If the above doesn't work, then search for some wireless drivers in `synaptic` with keywords like `wireless`, `dell` etc.